# python: efficient way to make large-scale check

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `test` with many lines, and each line has 3 numbers. I need to get `True` for each line where all 3 numbers are positive, and `False` otherwise. Currently I use

```
check = np.all((test[:] > 0), axis=1)
```

`test` looks like this

```
[[ 0.76717743 -0.14548865  0.10444938]
 [-0.349094    0.86043484 -0.03470421]
 [ 0.61281474 -0.5589774  -0.46888367]
 [ 0.106147   -0.15964074 -0.72297835]
 [-0.47496423  0.53561226 -0.56997515]
 [ 0.11404722 -0.19772103 -0.70308939]
 [ 0.05176676  0.68243443  0.10374478]
 [ 0.41054414 -0.37773413 -0.65230608]
 [-0.51045939  0.81814742 -0.34113701]
 [-0.30434684  0.229953   -0.6717718 ]
 [ 0.12726272 -0.2157578  -0.6968093 ]
 [-0.56914774  0.80530545 -0.27157462]
 [-0.10736854  0.76317726  0.08648359]
 [-0.30585015  0.85400552 -0.02213381]
 [ 0.81378956 -0.20719654  0.04194195]
 [-0.57842424  0.70255033 -0.39798076]
 [ 0.56074816 -0.54319019 -0.49967448]
 [ 0.72422859 -0.58427248 -0.37145212]
 [ 0.86456736 -0.45311164 -0.08229539]
 [ 0.86428591 -0.43964496 -0.0693436 ]
 [ 0.47937801 -0.51390972 -0.53733707]
 [ 0.85551894 -0.39396805 -0.01711862]
 [ 0.4737934  -0.54178454 -0.50940207]
 [ 0.15694062 -0.34735834 -0.61456285]]
```

I want to speed it up. What can I do?

Comment: Why are you making a copy of `test` with `test[:]`?

Comment: @ForceBru: While it is pointless, it's not a copy in NumPy. NumPy array slicing creates a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numexpr`:

```
import numexpr as ne

t0, t1, t2 = test[:,0], test[:,1], test[:,2]

check = ne.evaluate('(t0 > 0) & (t1 > 0) & (t2 > 0)')
```

Comment: Thanks, but does this really speed it up? I am looking at arrays with 100 000 000 elements.

Comment: @John Yes it does, by a big margin, according to some timing tests I did at my end. Did you test it out?

Comment: numexpr should be able to make this is fast as it is possible to make it without writing architecture-dependent SSE code. So pretty much as good as it gets.

Comment: I did. and generally found no difference - could you share your timings?

Comment: I posted timings for 1 million rows.  This has my vote.

Comment: @John, I had a 10x speed up here with a 1e6 elements array. Try to use `numexpr` from Anaconda, which is more optimized because it is compiled using MKL/VML, and also check that it is using all your machine cores.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option

```
(test > 0).all(1)
```

Consider `test`

```
test = np.random.randn(1000000, 3)
```

***time test***

[image]